# kzalloc an array of integers vs kmalloc and zeroing elements in for loop

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a struct which is something like

```
struct my_struct {
        u64 my_array[compile_time_size];
}
```

If I use kzalloc to allocate the struct, can I assume that all the elements of the array are initialized to 0 (across all architectures supported by linux kernel)?

Answer (score 0):

According to `core-api/memory-allocation.rst`

> The most straightforward way to allocate memory is to use a function
> from the kmalloc() family. And, to be on the safe side it's best to use
> routines that set memory to zero, like kzalloc() ...

So, yes, after allocation you can expect that memory is initialized with zero.